# Qt Harmattan N9 Aegis Manifest File in deb archive

Tags: qt, deb, meego, meego-harmattan, aegis

I have made an aegis manifest file following way, but it does not seem to be working. My application still complains about unprivileged access to tracker when I try to read/write. What I am doing wrong here?

The deb file content are following

```
_aegis  control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian-binary
```

**_aegis** file contents follows.

```
<aegis>
    <request policy="add">
        <credential name="TrackerReadAccess" />
        <for path="/opt/MyApp/bin/MyApp" />
   </request>
   <request policy="add">
       <credential name="TrackerWriteAccess" />
       <for path="/opt/MyApp/bin/MyApp" />
  </request>
  <request policy="add">
        <credential name="GRP::metadata-users" />
        <for path="/opt/MyApp/bin/MyApp" />
  </request>
</aegis>
```

Then inside **control.tar.gz** in **control** file I have the definition

```
Aegis-Manifest: included
```

So what goes wrong here?

Comment: Did you resolve it ? I suppose that you use try to use QtMobility Contacts. Did you're application have a source origin ?

Comment: Nope. This whole scenario still remains unresolved. I am using QtMobolity contacts.